# Overlay image on top of another image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I am doing a photo editing function that kinda works like a water mark.

The user selects the image A. After the image is selected, the user can select another image B to populate on top of the image A and they can move the image B around while image A is still static at the back.

After the placement of image B is done, the user can merge both image into one and save it as a **single image**.

I got the movement of image B function done but i am not sure how to actually combine the two images together.

**Edit 1:**
I want them to be either taken from the camera or gallery then combine the two images, B over A and save it to SD Card

**Edit 2:**
This is what i did to make the image B to move around my view. Now all i need is to connect the image b to the main image (which is in the background) and save it as a SD card. Is there a way to actually integrate both imageviews and its custom position (image B) and create a bitmap that can be saved to the sd card.

```
private ImageView img_additionalImage;

float x, y = 0.0f;
boolean isImageMoving = false;

img_additionalImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_additionalImage);
        img_additionalImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    isImageMoving = true;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (isImageMoving)
                    {
                        x = event.getRawX() - img_additionalImage.getWidth() / 2;
                        y = event.getRawY() - img_additionalImage.getHeight() / 2;
                        img_additionalImage.setX(x);
                        img_additionalImage.setY(y);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    isImageMoving = false;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**Edit 3:**
This is the code that gives me nullpointer when i call this.

MainActivity

```
CombineImages combineImages = new CombineImages(MainActivity.this);
img_additionalImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_additionalImage);
combineImages.combine(img_additionalImage);
```

The CombineImages class is what you have provided.

```
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.photosharingtest2/com.example.photosharingtest2.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3314)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at com.example.photosharingtest2.CombineImages.<init>(CombineImages.java:27)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at com.example.photosharingtest2.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:39)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
12-31 20:54:33.470: E/AndroidRuntime(6330):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: after combining the two images what you want? do u want to save this in SD card?

Comment: Yes. I want them to be either taken from the camera or gallery then combine the two images, B over A and save it to SD Card

Comment: @GrIsHu thank you for the solution. I am actually looking for the way to combine two imageview together to create a bitmap and then save it to sd card.

Comment: You can do that using the same way as i have shown you. You just need to make the Root layout of your both ImageView as `setDrawaingCacheEnabled()` and create a bitmap for that. @thhVictor

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to capture the image which you have rendered is to make the layout of your `ImageView` as `setDrawingCacheEnabled` to **true** which will allow you to capture the image of the imageview and convert it into the `Bitmap` and save it into sdcard.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview_here);
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Save the image as below into sdcard.

```
           String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File newDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        newDir.mkdirs();
        Random gen = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = gen.nextInt(n);
        String fotoname = "photo-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(newDir, fotoname);
        String s = file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.err.print("******************" + s);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { }
                     try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: So the imageview should be the one the user can move around and the bitmap is the image in the background? So in other words, it will be the Bitmap at the back and the imageview will be on top of it?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some thing simple for you. It is a view with canvas buffer, that have combine method. It draw images on buffer and display them. Your application need to have two views, `CombineImages` and the view your user is currently moving. Once he set it's position you call the CombineImages.combine to add that image to your view and than you can delete that image, you are ready now to add another image.

Currently I place all the images to top left, you should edit my code a bit to make this work with costume positions.

Also note that it is safe to call `CombineImages.combine` not from UI-Thread

```
    public class CombineImages extends View{

            private Bitmap buffer;
            private Canvas canvas;
            private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            public CombineImages(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
            }

            public CombineImages(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }

            public void combine(ImageView imageView){
                Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                combine(bitmap);
            }

            public void combine(Bitmap bitmap) {
                updateBuffer(bitmap);
                draw(canvas);
                postInvalidate();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                canvas.drawBitmap(buffer, matrix , null);
            }

            private void updateBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
                if(buffer == null){
                    createBuffer(bitmap);
                }
                else{
                    if(bitmap.getWidth() > buffer.getWidth() || bitmap.getHeight() > buffer.getHeight()){
                        Bitmap oldBuffer = buffer;
                        createBuffer(bitmap);
                        drawBitmnapToBuffer(oldBuffer);
                        oldBuffer.recycle();
                    }
                    drawBitmnapToBuffer(bitmap);
                }

                getLayoutParams().height = buffer.getHeight();
                getLayoutParams().width = buffer.getWidth();                
            }

            private void drawBitmnapToBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
                canvas.save();
                // add your translation logic here using canvas.translate(dx, dy); 
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
                canvas.restore();
            }

            private void createBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
                buffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
                canvas = new Canvas(buffer);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do i input the imageview of the one the user moved or the background image into CombineImages.combine(ImageView)?

Comment: @thhVictor The one the user move. After you used CombineImages.combine() it will marge the images and you can delete the image the user moved, it will be already part of the background.

Comment: When I called the combine method in CombineImages, it gives me nullpointer. I called this combineImages.combine(img_additionalImage); img_additionalImage is the image user moves and combineImages is the CombineImages class.

Comment: It sounds like your combineImages is null. Edit your question to show your complete code using my class. It will be easier for me to help you. Also show me the xml

Comment: I think its how i initialize my CombineImages class in my MainActivity. What are the two parameter for?

Comment: @thhVictor So you be able to initialize it from XML. To initialize it from code use the second contractor I just added.

Comment: I used the second constructor and i put this CombineImages combineImages = new CombineImages(this); but it still gives me null pointer

Comment: @thhVictor Debug your code to understand what variable is null.

Comment: @thhVictor nothing can be null at that code. Show me the full log cat error, your problem is some place else

Comment: @thhVictor your error is at: at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44233/discussion-between-thhvictor-and-babibu)

Answer (score 0):

if you have use RealtiveLayout or LinearLayout than you can capture that view by this way..

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
b.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, new FileOutputStream("/some/location/image.jpg"));
```

Where view is your View. The 95 is the quality of the JPG compression. And the file output stream is just that.